# Where is pandoc installed on Windows?

Tags: pandoc

I have a Windows 8 machine and I just ran the pandoc-1.13-windows.msi installer. The installer did not let me choose an install path, but it finished without error. I cannot run pandoc from the command line so I'm guessing I have to update the path. But I have no idea where pandoc was installed. Where is pandoc installed?

Comment: You can also enter %APPDATA%\Pandoc

Comment: after restart pandoc should be included in the path so you can use it in everywhere in cmd

Comment: Ridiculous that the documentation never says this anywhere.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Location for Pandoc - C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Pandoc

Answer (score 6):

With recent<sup>*</sup> versions of Pandoc, the program is installed for the individual user in their own profile at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Pandoc`, which, for most users will be `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Pandoc`.

If you choose to install for *All Users*, Pandoc is instead installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Pandoc` (you can change this location by clicking on the *Advanced* button).

In either case, when the Windows Setup program has finished installing the software, it should print a message showing the version of Pandoc and its installation path.

---

<sup>*</sup>Tested using the 64-bit installer for Windows 7 with Pandoc versions 1.19.2.1 to 2.1.3.

Comment: @StephenJacob I've just re-installed from the latest setup file and have updated my answer. Hope this helps.